# Good development workflow for small Front-End company?

Tags: wordpress, workflow

We are a small company where we do some Front-End Development, mainly using Wordpress.

I used to be the only person working on this, so development was done locally using MAMP, where I'd edit my files in Sublime Text 2, without any form of version control. When a site was done developing, I'd upload my sites via sFTP.

Now that our team is expanding, I realize this is not the most convenient workflow. I'm looking into Version Control, but the options for this are endless, and I'm not sure what the best option for us would be.

What would you guys think is the best way we can work together in an easy way?

Comment: MantisBT + GIT + MediaWiki works great within my team (team of 9)

Comment: Endless?  Not really.  Subversion, Mercurial, or Git are your choices.